# Is there any Xcode shortcut to open searched item in a new tab?

Tags: xcode, keyboard-shortcuts

For example I have used Command-Shift-F to search for some string in my entire project. And I see such string exists in 5 different files.

Is there any way I can click (while holding a key or something) on a file and make it open in a new tab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this would be in accordance with your Navigation preferences. You can set Double Click to mean Separate Tab, for example.

[image]

Comment: It's so interesting that Xcode is made *very* flexible while simple, but you just don't know of it. Do you know of any tutorial or something that goes over some other Xcode features/shortcuts that would make life easier?

Comment: Asking _me_ to recommend a tutorial is like asking Leo Tolstoy to recommend a novel...

Comment: :))))). But your tutorials are about Programming + and in between lines there are some _scattered_ Xcode tricks...not about Xcode tricks. right? I would appreciate if you can guide me to a tutorial (of yours) that you deem is appropriate

Comment: Nevertheless the thing we're talking about here _is_ covered in chapter 6 of my smaller book (at the end of this section: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch06.html#_the_navigator_pane).